# Saving a File that is the Target of a Hyperlink on a Web Page

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, xmlhttprequest

There are several links on an internal web page that generate and then open a file in Excel.

The URLs associated with the hyperlinks do not point to the files themselves. The files are generated at runtime.

For example:
`https://prodhost.company.com:45443/org/exportAdvancedSearchToXLS?f=worldRegion|worldRegion|worldRegion&v=NA|EMEA|APAC&e=%3D|%3D|%3D&qName=All%20Global%20Employees`

I need a way to save the file generated by the hyperlink to my local machine before performing operations on it. Essentially, to automate what right-clicking on the hyperlink and selecting "Save target as..." will do.

The following code (provided by [KittyKat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10036593/kittykat)) will save the generated file to my local machine but when I try to open the file, Excel is not able to recognize the format and generates the error

> "Excel cannot open the file 'test.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file."

```
Sub DownloadFile()
    Dim WinHttpReq As Object
    Dim oStream As Object
    Dim myURL As String
    Dim LocalFilePath As String

    LocalFilePath = "C:\Temp\test.xlsx"

    Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    WinHttpReq.Open "GET", gsADDRESS, False, "", ""  '("username", "password")
    WinHttpReq.send

    If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
        Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        oStream.Open
        oStream.Type = 1
        oStream.Write WinHttpReq.responseBody
        oStream.SaveToFile LocalFilePath, 2
        oStream.Close
    End If
End Sub
```

I tried saving the file as an .XLSX and .XLSB but to no avail.

Comment: It sounds like the .xlsx file is generated at runtime,  did you try to just use `LocalFilePath = "C:\Temp\`

Comment: Did you try saving as xls? Your hyperlink says "export advanced search to xls"

Comment: Did you try `Workbooks.Open(URLHERE)` ?   BTW the message you're seeing may indicate that the download is not an actually excel-format file, but instead an HTML table delivered with an Excel content-header.  Office will warn you about that type of thing.  https://jwgoerlich.com/excel-extension-hardening-and-web-applications/

Comment: is the url private/behind a login?

Comment: Zack E: I just tried your suggestion. It results in run-time error 3004: Application-defined or object-defined error.

Comment: seadoggie01: yes, saving as an xls versus xlsx worked!  Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to user [seadoggie01](https://stackoverflow.com/users/464394/seadoggie01), simply changing the file extension to XLS instead of XLSX made the difference. Thanks to everyone who responded.